# Remove surrounding double span tags with jQuery. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am confused about the use of a jquery selector and function for SPANs - and need some help :-)

In a big chunk of HTML-content I would like to remove **all** sorrunding SPAN tags defined with a specific class (including the child tag), **but keep the content of the inner span as it is (pure text)**.

**Here is a example of HTML content:**

```
 <div id="SaveInfo">
      <p>another content <span class="MyClass green">An expaination: <span>with a span</span></span> and more</p>
      <p>another content <span class="MyClass">An explaination: <span>Content in span</span></span> and more content</p>
      <!-- But NOT select this one (without .MyClass) -->
      <p>another content <span class="green">Content in span</span> and more content</p>
 </div>
```

**The output should be:**

(Removed some specific sorrounding SPANs)

```
 <div id="SaveInfo">
      <p>another content with a span and more</p>
      <p>another content Content in span and more content</p>
      <!-- But NOT removed this one (without .MyClass) -->
      <p>another content <span class="green">Content in span</span> and more content</p>
 </div>
```

---

**The content is inside a jquery loop like this:**

```
result += 'HTML content from each loop from before';
```

Then I use this:

```
   // set the content for further use
   jQuery('#SaveInfo').html(result);

   // removes instances of .RedClass from SaveInfo
   jQuery('#SaveInfo .RedClass').remove();
```

and it removes the unwanted DIVs with all it's content, but keep the rest. This works well.

NOW I need to remove the surrounding SPANs, BUT keep the content in the inner SPANs (as text).

The pattern is this:

Each:

```
<span class="MyClass anotherclass">Info text <span>main content</span></span>
```

should be transformed to:

```
main content
```

and keep it's place in the rest of the HTML.

So what I actually want is to select the content for each `span.MyClass span` and output as pure text in their respective place inside the HTML content.

I have looked at `unwrap()`, but havent got that to work as intended.

Now I work in a jQuery 1.7.1 environment.

I am at the end of my ability and ask for help here :-)

Comment: In your sample, did you mean for "Info text" to be left out from the result? It's not clear to me whether that should be stripped or included.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The "Info text" should also disappear. Only the content of the inner SPAN should be left.

Comment: I see that something is not clear: All spans with class MyClass should be removed. Only the content in the inner span should be kept. - In my case there is no span without a child as this is part of a bigger script, so I didn't think about a case with a span without a child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the path from the answer from before:

```
$('.MyClass').replaceWith(function(){
  var text = $(this).children("span").text();
  if(text!="") return text;
  else $(this).remove();
})
```

This won't put the contents of other inside children apart from span, on this case:

```
<span class="MyClass">An explaination: <b>Content in span</b></span>
```

And will delete MyClass spans without span child. This case:

```
<span class="MyClass">An explaination:</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vov36trq/4/

If you don't want to delete MyClass span without span inside:

```
$('.MyClass').replaceWith(function(){
  return $(this).children("span").text();
})
```

Comment: This seams to have fixed it :-) I have run a small test in my script and this seams to work well. Wife calls for dinner, but will be back and post final answer. Thank you!

Comment: how is this not a direct copy of the answer I provided?

Comment: Be careful with jQuery versions here and assumptions. If you set to 1.7.x and apply `MyClass` to the third (non-nested) outer span, the contents are wiped. You must ensure that a child `span` element exists explicitly before running `replaceWith()`. [Broken example with this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brendanmoore/vov36trq/2/) See my answer for workaround with 1.7.x.

Comment: @charlietfl, your first answer without edit, didn't have the children(), and wasn't what he asked. But in the time I posted you had changed it. So yes, your answer is correct, but I couldn't delete mine by then

Comment: I just came back from dinner. I didn't see the second version of @charlietfl 's answer. That worked well. I have woted both up. Will choose charlietfl's answer as the answer. Thank you both!

Comment: @Brendan understood contents should be wiped unless they had an inner span, and were to be replaced by their inner text.

Comment: @Preben, the only problem with charlietfl answer, it will replace the span wth the content of any child element, not just spans. Be it any of those tags <b> <i>, etc

Comment: Thank you. I tested, and you were right. Good catch. I am very thankful to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `replaceWith(function)`. This will iterate through all instances and treat them individually

```
$('.MyClass').replaceWith(function(){
   return $(this).children().text();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qk2jo0mt/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: I am testing this. I played with the fiddle, and that looked very promising :-)

Comment: Be careful with jQuery versions here and assumptions. If you set to 1.7.x and apply `MyClass` to the third (non-nested) outer span, the contents are wiped. You must ensure that a child `span` element exists explicitly before running `replaceWith()`. [Broken example with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanmoore/qk2jo0mt/5/) See my answer for workaround with 1.7.x.

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my comment to include a fork of your fiddle showing a breaking case. Changes I made from yours were 1) Added `MyClass` to the third `span` (has no child `span`) and 2) Switch jQuery resource to 1.7.x since @Preben specified a 1.7.1 environment.

Comment: @Brendan that's not broken, you have a different interpretaion...OP wants the spans gone

Comment: You are assuming that the special class and nested span are a single linked condition. I am assuming they are two separate conditions and the replacement happens only when both conditions are true. The OP has to decide which version applies. My main point that this matters for jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know if `MyClass` will only exist in cases of nested `span` elements?

Because you specified jQuery 1.7.x, I chose to not make that assumption because the other solutions break. My version iterates through the child `span` elements instead and replaces the parent. If the child does not exist, nothing will be changed on the parent element, even if `MyClass` is applied.

```
$("span.MyClass>span").each(function () {
    var childText = $(this).text();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $(parent).replaceWith(childText);
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanmoore/r624dsbo/)

Comment: OP clearly stated they wanted all of the spans gone ... you aren't doing that if the child span doesn't exist

Comment: Only in the case of a nested child, is my interpretation. The OP includes a sample output with a `span` left intact in the third `p` element. Note that I have indicated that both my comments and solution are dependent on the assumptions made. If OP knows that `MyClass` will **only** ever appear when it is known that a child `span` exists, your solution is fine. If that cannot be guaranteed, however, your solution (in jQ 1.7.1) would replace the childless-instances of `MyClass` with an empty string. I interpret this as unwanted behaviour.

Comment: the one at the end of your demo has the class and you aren't removing it. Don't fault others when you decide to make up your own interpretations. OP wrote `remove all sorrunding SPAN tags defined with a specific class ` which seems quite clear to me

Comment: I don't think my interpretation is unreasonable. The OP asked for "remove all *surrounding* SPAN tags defined *with a specific class*"  to be replaced. It is at best ambiguous whether those two conditions are coupled or independent.

Comment: that's fine , ask for clarification before faulting others based on your own assumptions

Comment: I never said you were wrong. I said be careful based on the assumptions and clearly stated the breaking conditions.